# how to install c compiler without internet connectivity on opensuse 15?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, opensuse, suse, redhat-containers

I am having OpenSUSE Linux server 15 without internet connectivity and I was trying to install Nginx from the source.
while installing Nginx dependency pcre from the source I am getting the below error.

```
ip-10-10-4-30:/home/ec2-user/softwares # cd pcre-8.44/
ip-10-10-4-30:/home/ec2-user/softwares/pcre-8.44 # ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... no
checking whether make supports nested variables... no
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) no
checking whether make supports the include directive... no
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/home/ec2-user/softwares/pcre-8.44':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details
```

Comment: Download gcc, gcc-c++, cpp, libstdc++-devel, glibc-devel, linux-kernel-headers, libxcrypt-devel : Example Leap http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/leap/ → → example 15.0 http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/leap/15.0/repo/oss/x86_64/ ..... Install packages with `# rpm -Uvh package.rpm package.rpm package.rpm package.rpm`

Answer (score 1):

nginx is available for OpenSUSE. One thing you might try is to download the DVD ISO image then use imagewriter to write it to a USB flash drive. You can then add it as a software repository using Yast and install nginx, gcc, or whatever else you need that way.  It isn't complete, but it should contain enough.

You might try installing the pcre-devel and the various libpcre RPMs which has version 8.45.
Here is what my system currently has installed (OpenSUSE 15.3):

```
rpm -q -a | grep pcre
pcre-devel-8.45-20.10.1.x86_64
libpcre16-0-8.45-20.10.1.x86_64
libpcre1-debuginfo-8.41-6.4.2.x86_64
libpcre2-16-0-10.31-3.3.1.x86_64
pcre-doc-8.45-20.10.1.noarch
pcre-tools-8.45-20.10.1.x86_64
libpcre1-32bit-8.45-20.10.1.x86_64
libpcre1-8.45-20.10.1.x86_64
pcre2-tools-10.31-3.3.1.x86_64
libpcre2-posix2-10.31-3.3.1.x86_64
pcre2-doc-10.31-3.3.1.noarch
libpcre2-8-0-10.31-3.3.1.x86_64
libpcrecpp0-8.45-20.10.1.x86_64
libpcreposix0-8.45-20.10.1.x86_64
libpcre2-32-0-10.31-3.3.1.x86_64
pcre-debugsource-8.41-6.4.2.x86_64
```

You will also need gcc7.

pcre-devel has the following dependencies, which I assume you will also require if compiling it:

```
rpm -q --requires pcre-devel
/bin/sh
/usr/bin/pkg-config
libpcre1 = 8.45
libpcre16-0 = 8.45
libpcrecpp0 = 8.45
libpcreposix0 = 8.45
libstdc++-devel
pkgconfig(libpcre)
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1
```

gcc and g++ also have a number of dependencies:

```
rpm -q --requires gcc7
binutils
cpp7 = 7.5.0+r278197-4.30.1
glibc-devel
ld-linux-x86-64.so.2()(64bit)
ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit)
libasan4 >= 7.5.0+r278197-4.30.1
libatomic1 >= 7.5.0+r278197-4.30.1
libc.so.6()(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.11)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.3)(64bit)
libcilkrts5 >= 7.5.0+r278197-4.30.1
libgcc_s1 >= 7.5.0+r278197-4.30.1
libgmp.so.10()(64bit)
libgomp1 >= 7.5.0+r278197-4.30.1
libisl.so.15()(64bit)
libitm1 >= 7.5.0+r278197-4.30.1
liblsan0 >= 7.5.0+r278197-4.30.1
libm.so.6()(64bit)
libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
libmpc.so.3()(64bit)
libmpfr.so.6()(64bit)
libmpx2 >= 7.5.0+r278197-4.30.1
libmpxwrappers2 >= 7.5.0+r278197-4.30.1
libtsan0 >= 7.5.0+r278197-4.30.1
libubsan0 >= 7.5.0+r278197-4.30.1
libz.so.1()(64bit)
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1
```

nginx lists the following dependencies for my system (I do not have it installed):

```
libpthread.so.0()(64bit)
libdl.so.2()(64bit)
libz.so.1()(64bit)
libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
libcrypto.so.1.1()(64bit)
libcrypto.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit)
libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.3.2)(64bit)
libxml2.so.2()(64bit)
libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.4.30)(64bit)
/usr/bin/perl
libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.6.0)(64bit)
libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.28)(64bit)
libssl.so.1.1()(64bit)
libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit)
libcrypt.so.1()(64bit)
libpcre.so.1()(64bit)
libcrypt.so.1(XCRYPT_2.0)(64bit)
libxslt.so.1()(64bit)
libxslt.so.1(LIBXML2_1.0.11)(64bit)
libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_1)(64bit)
libperl.so()(64bit)
libxslt.so.1(LIBXML2_1.0.18)(64bit)
libgd.so.3()(64bit)
libexslt.so.0()(64bit)
perl = 5.26.1
/bin/sh
shadow
sysuser-shadow
```

It also recommends:

```
logrotate
vim-plugin-nginx
nginx-module-fancyindex
nginx-module-geoip2
nginx-module-headers-more
nginx-module-http-flv
```

though I do not know the dependencies of these modules.

To compile it you will likely need the -devel packages for many of these.